# Finding a stochastic matrix $M$ such that $M^{7} = I$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find a stochastic matrix $M$ such that $M^{7} = I$.

Stochastic matrix just meaning that every entry must be between $0$ and $1$, and the sum of the columns must equal $1$.

For example,

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
0.7 & 0.6 \\
0.3 & 0.4
\end{bmatrix}$$

is a stochastic matrix, but $M^{7} \neq I$. The only issue is that I don't want $M^{k} = I$ for any $k < 7$.  Is there any way that I can do this? I tried diagonalizing the matrix, but it didn't get me anywhere. Also, I made note of the fact that $M^{-1} = M^{6}$, and tried working with that, but I didn't get anywhere.

I don't care what the dimensions of $M$ are, by the way. What is a good procedure for finding such matrices?

Comment: The definition of a stochastic matrix also requires to have row (or column) sum to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a $7 \times 7$ linear transformation that maps $e_1$ to $e_2$,$e_2$ to $e_3$,$\cdots$ ,$e_6$ to $e_7$, $e_7$ to $e_1$. The matrix of this LT has the desire property. Here $e_j$'s are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^{7}$.

Comment: But it will be matrix $7\times7$. No? I think, he looks for $2\times2$.

Comment: @Hat \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: @Hat Actually, this is the inverse of the proposed map, but it also works.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think you did not read the question fully. OP is not looking for a $2 \times 2$ matrix.